# How to prevent a program from modifing xdg-open settings without editing its source code?

Tags: xorg

I am using a software which always set `text/html={its name}` after every startup with no reasons (seems to be a bug). Is there any method to restrict it from doing so?

Comment: Is it modifying your `~/.config/mimeapps.list` file? if so, perhaps you can use `chattr` to make the file immutable?

Comment: @steeldriver I am not sure whether it modifies the list directly or calls some commands or functions. I will try making that software running in as an individual user, which has no permission to modify this file.

Comment: If you know which binary file is doing it, you could try to find the string `text/html=` in it and replace the first character `t` in the binary file by a nul so as to truncate the string. But you really need to find what method it is using to do the edit. `strace` and `ltrace` can be used on a binary to see all the system calls (like write) and library calls, for example.